# Missing reputation

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Yesterday (in CET_TimeZone), I posted two answers on Stack Overflow:

- [How format the output of decimal numbers via the JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772195/how-format-the-output-of-decimal-numbers-via-the-joptionpane/7772259#7772259)
- [What part of my code is in the event dispatch queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773545/what-part-of-my-code-is-in-the-event-dispatch-queue/7773794#7773794)

Something went wrong with points, as you can see in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel?tab=reputation#page_1-view_time) and in the pop-up.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Can a moderator check if this is a general problem that's occurring for other users too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations! You have reached the reputation cap.

You cannot get more than 200 reputation points on a given day from up-votes.

Read more about it in the [reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: clear answer that solved my knowledges lack +1